# Filtering aws ebs volumes by Time Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to write a script that will delete all available volumes that are up for more than 1 hour.

So I took the line that filters the volumes by state

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available | jq '.Volumes[]'
```

And I tried to combine it with another query I have for filtering snapshots by time creation

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner self --output json | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime < "'$(date --date='-1 month' '+%Y-%m-%d')'") | [.Description, .StartTime, .SnapshotId]'
```

So I combined this query but it does not return any volume

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available | jq '.Volumes[] | select(.CreateTime < "'$(date --date='-1 hour' '+%Y-%m-%d')'") | [.VolumeId]'
```

And another weird thing, if I replace CreateTime with blabla the query does not fail but returns me the volume

```
~ $ aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available | jq '.Volumes[] | select(.blabla < "'$(date --date='-1 hour' '+%Y-%m-%d')'") | [.VolumeId]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found another way to do this

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available --query "Volumes[?(CreateTime<'$(date --date='-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')')].[VolumeId]" --output text
```